# Using python classes (OOP) to create FUNCTIONAL turtle objects?

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I'm currently coding in python to create a somewhat similar game to 'Space Invaders'.
It was going well until I tried to make all of my invader objects (which are turtles) by using a class, so I could easily manipulate the number of enemies I wanted when I adjust the difficulty.

However now I have done this I have removed functionality to the TURTLE objects as they are now seen as CLASS OBJECTS instead. Therefore I cannot use turtle module features such as `[object].xcor` and `[object].ycor` which are somewhat essential.

Here is the code that makes the class of objects:

```
class invaders():
def __init__(self, speed, position):
    self = turtle.Turtle()   # how I thought I could make them turtle objects (didn't work)
    self.color('red')   
    self.shape('circle')
    self.up()
    self.setposition(position)
    self.speed(speed)

def change_speed(newSpeed):
    invader.speed(newSpeed)   # use to make new speed if changing difficulty  #variable.changeSpeed(newSpeed)

def change_position(x, y):
    invader.setposition(x, y)
```

I have also attached a photo below so you can see the difference between the two objects I am talking about.

[image: the errors underneath the text aren't relevant]

Comment: Change `self = turtle.Turtle()` to `self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()` . Then you can access that specific turtle by `ObjectName.turlte` and get the coordinates like `ObjectName.turlte.xcor & ObjectName.turlte.ycor`

Comment: @Stack so I would instead do: "self.turtle.color('red')" ?

Comment: if you want to access color and shape variables, change `self.color('red')` to `self.color = 'red'` and similarly change shape also. And to access color and shape of turtle use `ObjectName.color` and `ObjectName.shape`

Comment: @Stack ah thank you so much! ^_^

Comment: No Problem, happy to help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Self = turtle.Turtle()` should be `self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()`

Thanks @Stack

Answer (score 5):

Objects can *contain* another class instance or objects can *be* (*subclass*) an instance of another class.  What you initially described and attempted was *subclassing*, what you settled for was *contain*.  Here's a (Python3) example of how we might subclass turtle to make an invader:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Invader(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, speed, position):
        super().__init__(shape='circle', visible=False)
        self.color('red')
        self.penup()
        self.setposition(position)
        self.speed(speed)
        self.showturtle()

    def change_speed(self, newSpeed):
        self.speed(newSpeed)

    def change_position(self, x, y):
        self.setposition(x, y)

invader = Invader('slowest', (100, 100))

invader.change_position(-100, -100)

invader.change_speed('fastest')

invader.pendown()  # try an original turtle method

invader.change_position(100, -100)

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Now when we create an invader instance, it describes itself as such:

```
>>> fred = Invader("normal", (0, 0))
>>> fred
<__main__.Invader object at 0x1021784e0>
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can just use self.turtle.color("red") to access the color attribute of the turtle.